# Flex React Native -- How to have content break to next line with flex when content reaches edge

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I have a list of icons inside my styled container that are displayed in a `flexDirection:'row'` but when there is more icons than width of view, they dont break to next line, but continue on to the right out of view. How do I get the content to break to the next line if it reaches max width?

Styling:

```js
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH, //width of screen
    flexDirection:'row',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    marginTop:40,
    paddingLeft:10,
    paddingRight:10,
    flex: 1,
  },
  iconText:{
    paddingLeft:10,
    paddingRight:10,
    paddingTop:10,
    paddingBottom:10
  },
});
```

Render:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>

      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.changeIcon(indexToChange, icons[0])}
        underlayColor='#F7F7F7'>
          <Text style={styles.iconText}><IonIcons name={icons[0]} size={30} color="#555" /></Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.changeIcon(indexToChange, icons[1])}
        underlayColor='#F7F7F7'>
          <Text style={styles.iconText}><IonIcons name={icons[1]} size={30} color="#555" /></Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.changeIcon(indexToChange, icons[2])}
        underlayColor='#F7F7F7'>
          <Text style={styles.iconText}><IonIcons name={icons[2]} size={30} color="#555" /></Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      ...//more continued on

</View>
```

When the icons reach the width to the right they dont break to the bottom. Is this possible?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can add `flexWrap: 'wrap'` and `alignItems: flex-start` (or anything other than `stretch` to your container style.

If you don't specify `align-items` or if you set `align-items: stretch`, each column in the first row will take as much height as possible, pushing the second row below kind of like in the screenshot below:

[image: With no alignItems specified]

Comment: The content on the right now is hidden. It is not wrapping down though. Do I need a new flex container for each row?

Comment: @Chipe you can just add `align-items: flex-start` for example and it should work as you want it. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick! Is there any references around, tutorials you recommend to learn flex?

Comment: @Chipe For Html I'd recommend https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and http://flexboxfroggy.com/
Flexboxes in react-native is pretty similar to html flexboxes

Answer (score 18):

For my case, I only needed to add `flex-shrink: 1` or `flexShrink: 1`, to the *parent* of my Text component that I wanted to wrap.

I did not need or benefit from `align-items: flex-start` or `flex-wrap: wrap` etc. Again, might just be my use-case, but that worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

just put `multiline` as follows

```
          <TextInput
                multiline
                style={[ styles.input, propStyleTextInput, {flexShrink: 1}]}
                onChangeText={(e) => onChangeNumber(e, id)}
                value={number}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                keyboardType={keyboardType}
            />
```